# Navigation to the webpage was canceled in MMC

Tags: mmc

I am running an application that runs on MMC but what is displayed on right pane is "Navigation to the webpage was canceled". I thought this error message only appears on IE but it also appears on MMC.

Do you have any idea what may have caused this? Have you encountered this before?

Comment: what application? Does it embed a webpage for a UI somehow? More information would be super useful.

Comment: It's an Infor application. When I clicked "Refresh the page", it says "Make sure the web address h t t p : / / %7b97ad17da-70a5-45b9-9e10-deaa3d26e17d%7d is correct". So it's possible to embed a webpage in MMC?

Comment: According tho this, yeah https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb742441.aspx#XSLTsection124121120120 (search the page for the string  web page). Dosen't get us any nearer to "what's broken" - looks almost like hex but that dosen't decode to anything sensible.